# Is it possible to write it's own logon and authenticate application for Windows 7?

Tags: windows, authentication

I know some of biometric logon authenticate application for Windows. How do they did this? Can I write my own logon authenticate application? I want to use my IR based remote control to authenticate? I need to learn a lot. It works with my ir based remote control but I can only use numbers for my password? I don't know how to type letters and also capitals with my ir based remote control

Comment: You need to write a *credential provider*. Good luck.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, have a look at [Logon and Authentication Technology Page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780455%28v=ws.10%29) on technet.  You basically want to write a [`SSPI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/`SSPS` handler

Comment: Thanks, but it works with my ir based remote control but I can only use numbers for my password? I don't know how to type letters and also capitals with my ir based remote control?